# FlutterError: Unable to load asset

Tags: flutter, assets

This is the folder structure of my app

```
.idea
.vscode
android
build
fonts
 Oxygen-Bold.tff
 Oxygen-Light.tff
 Oxygen-Regular.tff
images
 pizza0.png
 pizza1.png
ios
lib
 ui
  home.dart
 main.dart
test
.gitignore
.metadata
.packages
app_widgets.iml
pubspec.lock
pubspec.yaml
README.md
```

In my `pubspec.yaml` file, I load the fonts and assets like this

```
flutter:

uses-material-design: true

assets:
  - images/pizza0.png
  - images/pizza1.png

fonts:
  - family: Oxygen
    fonts:
      - asset: fonts/Oxygen-Regular.ttf
      - asset: fonts/Oxygen-Bold.ttf
        weight: 700
      - asset: fonts/Oxygen-Light.ttf
        weight: 300
```

I'm not getting any errors for this `pubspec.yaml`, and running `flutter packages get` gives an exit code of 0.

In my home.dart I have the following class:

```
class PizzaImageWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AssetImage pizzaAsset = AssetImage('images/pizza0.png');
    Image image = Image(image: pizzaAsset, width: 400, height: 400);
    return Container(
      child: image,
    );
  }
}
```

Which I use elsewhere, in order to show the image (code omitted):

```
        ),
        PizzaImageWidget(),
      ],
```

The building gives no errors. Flutter Doctor -v doesn't give any errors, neither does Flutter Analyze -v. The .apk seems to build just fine but when the app opens up on my phone I get the following error in asset_bundle.dart:

> Exception has occurred. FlutterError (Unable to load asset:
> images/pizza0.png)

The error is thrown by this class in the asset_bundle.dart file:

```
/// An [AssetBundle] that loads resources using platform messages.
class PlatformAssetBundle extends CachingAssetBundle {
  @override
  Future<ByteData> load(String key) async {
    final Uint8List encoded = utf8.encoder.convert(Uri(path: Uri.encodeFull(key)).path);
    final ByteData asset =
        await BinaryMessages.send('flutter/assets', encoded.buffer.asByteData());
    if (asset == null)
      throw FlutterError('Unable to load asset: $key');
    return asset;
  }
}
```

This happens both for the pizza0.png file as well as the pizza1.png file. The files are visible in the tree structure, both in Windows Explorer as in VS Code. The font assets load without issue.

This is the output I am getting when running Flutter Run -v:

> [+1068 ms] I/flutter ( 6489): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE
> SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════ [   +9
> ms] I/flutter ( 6489): The following assertion was thrown resolving an
> image codec: [   +2 ms] I/flutter ( 6489): Unable to load asset:
> images/pizza0.png [   +2 ms] I/flutter ( 6489): [   +1 ms] I/flutter (
> 6489): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: [   +2 ms]
> I/flutter ( 6489): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load
> (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7) [   +1 ms]
> I/flutter ( 6489):  [   +1 ms] I/flutter (
> 6489): #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync
> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:429:44) [   +1 ms]
> I/flutter ( 6489):  [   +1 ms] I/flutter (
> 6489): #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load
> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:414:14) [   +1 ms]
> I/flutter ( 6489): #3      ImageProvider.resolve..
> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:267:86) [   +4 ms]
> I/flutter ( 6489): #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent
> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:143:20) [   +3 ms]
> I/flutter ( 6489): #5      ImageProvider.resolve.
> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:267:63) [   +3 ms]
> I/flutter ( 6489): (elided 8 frames from package dart:async) [   +1
> ms] I/flutter ( 6489): [   +1 ms] I/flutter ( 6489): Image provider:
> AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "images/pizza0.png") [   +3 ms]
> I/flutter ( 6489): Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle:
> PlatformAssetBundle#20fc8(), name: "images/pizza0.png", [   +1 ms]
> I/flutter ( 6489): scale: 1.0) [   +2 ms] I/flutter ( 6489):
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Comment: @diegoveloper Yes, the fonts work but both images give this error.

Comment: are you using spaces before the assets keyword?

Comment: The yaml file is OK. I have a yaml extension in VS Code which gives no errors, and yamlint.com says it's good as well.

Comment: yep, you don't get errors if you don't add indentation but you couldn't get the image

Comment: I have same issue, I found warning that might be useful while building: "Error: unable to find directory entry in pubspec.yaml"

Comment: Guess I had 2 clones of the repo and put images in the one I wasn't using lol

Comment: I solved this with close Android Studio and emulator, then give `flutter clean`.

Comment: If all solutions don't work, try to add package name aside the asset name: SvgPicture.asset('assets/asset_name.svg', package: package_name);

Answer (score 342, accepted):

You should consider the indentation for `assets`

```
flutter:

  assets:
    - images/pizza1.png
    - images/pizza0.png
```

More details:

```
flutter:

[2 whitespaces or 1 tab]assets:
[4 whitespaces or 2 tabs]- images/pizza1.png
[4 whitespaces or 2 tabs]- images/pizza0.png
```

After all this, you can make a hot-restart.

Comment: If I do that, flutter packages get fails:

Running "flutter packages get" in app_widgets...                
Error on line 40, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.
  assets:
  ^

pub get failed (65)
exit code 65

Comment: just add two spaces

Comment: Spaces where exactly? Right now I have the words flutter, and assets sticking all the way to the left with no spaces. If I add a space, or two, before the word assets I get the exit code 65 error.

Comment: 2 white spaces (or 1 tab) before assets  and 4 white spaces (or 2 tabs) before - images...

Comment: Nope. Gives the same error... This is my full file by the way: https://pastebin.com/ygzkTgHG

Comment: Turns out the "uses-material-design: true" is the culprit here. Commenting that out, or changing the indendation of that part makes it work.

Seems like a weird oversight/bug that the fonts work just fine like that but the assets don't.

Comment: Matthias' comment above worked for me, but I should note that even with that set to true, SOME of my assets worked while others did not. It looks like it is just something incorrect on the flutter end.

Comment: Make sure that you are adding assets to 
"flutter:"           

not to 
"dependancies:
   flutter:"
             
which is first one in the pubspec.yaml

Comment: Matthias comment did the trick, commenting and uncommenting fixed it. Definitly something is wrong in flutter

Comment: I also have the same issue when I was developing my first app with dependency. in pupspec.yaml . These are sensitves. This was a solution for me.

Comment: Thanks for the solution ...I spent a lot time on this.

Comment: Yes. Don't forget assets is below (inside) flutter

Comment: I also got the indentation wrong 

Answer (score 160):

Running `flutter clean` solved my issue.

[More about this error](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17870)

Comment: Thanks. This was my problem. Actually I had the wrong indentation too. So people should check their indentation and also run `flutter clean`.

Comment: flutter clean worked.  I wonder why pubspec.yml changes don't automatically run flutter clean

Comment: From Android Studio, in my case the issue would happen only when using hot-reload. Triggering a rebuild by pressing the STOP button and then the PLAY button solved it (I'm using the integrated Android emulator)

Comment: @Michele I'm with you. I had to do the hot restart. That fixed it

Comment: Restart Android Studio after running `flutter clean`. Worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me as well, if you get a bunch of red "no references" just restart Android Studio.

Comment: this worked for me. make sure to run flutter pub get after flutter clean if u get red errors.

Answer (score 84):

Considering your app will have multiple assets it is better to reference the assets folder and not the asset itself. Ensure you use proper indentations as the `pubspec.yaml` is indent sensitive.

```yaml
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/
```

and then you can access the image asset by prefixing the referenced folder path

```dart
Image.asset('images/pizza1.png', width:300, height:100)
```

> Note that when an asset’s path is specified in the assets section of pubspec.yaml, the build process looks for any files with the same name in adjacent subdirectories. Such files are then included in the asset bundle along with the specified asset.

See [Adding asset variants](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets-and-images?gclid=Cj0KCQjw6cKiBhD5ARIsAKXUdyb7f-PZCXCfOylaF24co7lGIosv3IhjWqj6TVJGZMo-OjiRf_c2IPIaAnd_EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds#asset-variants) section in the official flutter docs

Comment: Worked in my case

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me. I have to import every single image for it to work and I have thousands of them.

Comment: I just checked and it seems to be working as of `stable 2.5.2`, I  would love to take a look if you could share your `pubspec.yaml` as a gist

Comment: this is work, its best to check what are the assets folders given in the pubspecs.yml

Comment: For some reason, all of a sudden none of my assets were loading anymore, I was using the same yaml config and referencing "assets/" in the path. I had to remove assets/ to make it work again. No idea why it regressed like that with no code change...

Answer (score 35):

Encountered the same issue with a slightly different code. In my case, I was using a "assets" folder subdivided into sub-folders for assets (sprites, audio, UI).

My code was simply at first in *pubspec.yaml*- alternative would be to detail every single file.

```
flutter:

  assets:
    - assets
```

Indentation and flutter clean was not enough to fix it. **The files in the sub-folders** were not loading by flutter.  It seems like flutter needs to be "taken by the hand" and not looking at sub-folders without explicitly asking it to look at them. This worked for me:

```
flutter:

  assets:
    - assets/sprites/
    - assets/audio/
    - assets/UI/
```

So I had to detail each folder and each sub-folder that contains assets (mp3, jpg, etc). Doing so made the app work and **saved me tons of time as the only solution detailed above would require me to manually list 30+ assets** while the code here is just a few lines and easier to maintain.

Comment: On a side note - there are packages like audioplayers that will not load assets properly if you use code like plyer.play('assets/audio/sound.mp3') in your dart file widgets. While plyer.play('audio/sound.mp3') will load properly. That also can create some very frustrating debugging. So I wanted to add it.

Comment: This worked for me. I had the same problem

Answer (score 30):

For me,

1. `flutter clean`,
2. Restart the android studio and emulator,
3. giving full patth in my image

   ```
   image: AssetImage(
     './lib/graphics/logo2.png'
      ),
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
    );
   ```

these three steps did the trick.

Comment: This one works well for me

Answer (score 13):

I also had this problem. I think there is a bug in the way Flutter caches images. My guess is that when you first attempted to load `pizza0.png`, it wasn't available, and Flutter has cached this failed result. Then, even after adding the correct image, Flutter still assumes it isn't available.

This is all guess-work, based on the fact that I had the same problem, and calling this once on app start fixed the problem for me:

```
imageCache.clear();
```

This clears the image cache, meaning that Flutter will then attempt to load the images fresh rather than search the cache.

PS I've also found that you need to call this whenever you change any existing images, for the same reason - Flutter will load the old cached version. The alternative is to rename the image.

Comment: please specify what it does and where to use it, that completes your answer :)

Comment: @James Allen: you are an absolute genius. To figure that out , you're a smart guy.

Answer (score 12):

> inside pubspec.yaml, DON'T USE TAB!

```
flutter:
<space><space>assets:
<space><space><space><space>assets/
```

example:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    assets/
```

Comment: This worked for me, tried all answers above and this is what fixed it. lol.

Answer (score 12):

Some times cache will create a problem so first run

```
flutter clean
```

after this run

```
flutter pub get
```

Comment: make sure you put "/" such as "assets/icons/" not "assets/icons"

Answer (score 11):

i just Re-run My app instead of just hot Reload.

Comment: re-run the app solves the problem. i wasted my 10m time ignoring this answer and keep trying check syntax+tab/spaces etc.. :P

Answer (score 10):

Actually the problem is in pubspec.yaml,
I put all images to  `assets/images/` and

This wrong way

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
  - images/
```

**Correct**

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
  - assets/images/
```

Answer (score 9):

if you're developing flutter packages, please add package param after image path like this:

```
AssetImage('images/heart.png', package: 'my_icons') // my_icons is your plugin name, in flutter plugin is also a package.
```

Here is the link from flutter docs
https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

Answer (score 8):

I haved a similar problem, I fixed here:

```
uses-material-design: true
 assets:
   - assets/images/
```

After, do:

```
Flutter Clean
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case a restart didn't help.

### I had to **uninstall** the app and then **run everything again**.

It did worked!

Comment: one of the worst things about flutter, takes me 35 minutes to load an image every time

Comment: Yeah me too, for some reason every time I hot restart, it always leads to the same error, namely throwing an image error into the `image_provider.dart` file to the `_loadAsync` method. I have to stop the debug session and start it again

Answer (score 6):

After you did all things and still not working, try:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

sometimes after updating *pubspec.yaml* file, it can not run pub get although it shows it is running.

try commands above

Answer (score 5):

1. you should start image path with **assets** word:

`image: AssetImage('assets/images/pizza0.png')`

2. you must add each sub folder in a new line in pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that worked for me to mention THE WHOLE PATH in the CODE. That is you must mention the image path from the root directory on the code page, in YAML it works with the top-level directory.

You probably can't get away only with the main directory path in code, I have tried a lot and that's the only thing that works.

hope it solved the issue and saved your time.

The 1st image is of code and the second is of the yaml.

[image: code]

[image: yaml]

Comment: This should have more upvotes. It's unfortunate that it works on Chrome with the shorter path, but not on Windows or Android and iOS.

Answer (score 4):

There is clearly some sort of flutter bug. This is my directory structure:

```
<project>/assets/images/myimage.png
```

This is what I have in pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

And this is how it used to work and still works when I compile for web:

```
const DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("images/myimage.png")
```

But it will only work when I compile for ios like this:

```
const DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("assets/images/myimage.png")
```

Luckily adding "assets/" as a prefix works now in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

This is issue has almost driven me nut in the past. To buttress what others have said, after making sure that all the indentations on the yaml file has been corrected and the problem persist, run a 'flutter clean' command at the terminal in Android studio. As at flutter 1.9, this should fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

While I was loading a new image in my asset folder, I just encountered the problem every time.

I run `flutter clean` & then restarted the Android Studio. Seems like flutter packages caches the asset folder and there is no mechanism to update the cache when a developer adds a new image in the project (Personal thoughts).

Answer (score 3):

Make a habit to check **pubspec.yaml** when you are struggling to load an image in a Flutter project. Most of the time, the problem is with it.

The correct way is mentioned below. Do not use the Tab key to keep the spaces. Instead, use the Space bar.

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: tru
  assets:
    - images/image1.jpg
```

And make sure you include the **same correct path** in your dart file.

- **One trick I always use is renaming the image with a very short name to avoid typo errors.**

Hope this would be helpful to anyone who faces these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 3):

If everything is ok, correct path, correct pubspec spaces, etc, the last thing that could cause this is cache. You can close the simulator and start your application again, it helps for my case.

Answer (score 3):

One more answer in the mix:

My pubspec.yaml looked like this:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/us_defs/
    - assets/eu_defs/
    - assets/images/
```

and in the invoking code:

```
Center(
  child: Image(
    image: AssetImage('assets/images/<name.png>')
  )
)
```

(The `*_defs` folders contain json files for various other purposes and I can load them just fine.)

But, the image wouldn't load, no matter what I tried. Checked and double checked the indent spacing, spelling, invoked `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`, cold started the app, etc.  Tried referencing `'images/<name.png>'` vs `'assets/images/<name.png>'`.

Nada.

Finally, I lifted the `images` folder to the top level under the project folder:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/us_defs/
    - assets/eu_defs/
    - images/    <-- now a top level folder
```

and in the invoking code:

```
Center(
  child: Image(
    image: AssetImage('images/<name.png>');
  )
)
```

... and that worked.

I have no idea why.

Now, I'd rather keep the `images` folder in `assets` since it fits my sensibilities, but if this reorg gets me going, I'll live with it.

Answer (score 3):

```
  assets:
    - assets/
```

It was working until I upgraded my Flutter version to 3.12.0 .

So the fix was for me to load images was to change it like below

```
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue I corrected it, you just need to put the two(uses-material-design: true and assets) in the same column and click in the upgrade dependencies but before restart android studio.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the file names do not contain special characters such as ñ for example

Answer (score 2):

Another cause of similar problem:
On Windows you should not use \ sign as directory separator. So

instead of

```
AssetImage('images\heart.png')
```

use

```
AssetImage('images/heart.png')
```

It can be a bug of Windows version of Flutter. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Dec 25th, 2019 :**

Whoever facing issue regarding Image not showing in Flutter , let me give you simple checkpoints :

1. Image.asset('assets/images/photo1.png');  -- here make sure dont use / (forward slash ) before assets.
2. YAML file always be clear dont use space , instead use TAB.
3. YAML file add entries for assets. as mentioned in above comment.

First point is very important

Answer (score 1):

This issue still existed in my case even after,
`flutter clean` (deletes build folder) and *proper indentations* in yaml file

It got fixed by itself, as it could be an issue related to Android Studio.

**Fix 1)** Restart the emulator in **Cold Boot** mode, In Android Studio,
after clicking *List Virtual Devices*  button, click  *Drop down arrow*  (last icon next to edit icon) 
=> Choose *Cold Boot Now* option. If issue still exist, follow as below

**Fix 2**) After **changing the emulator virtual device** as a workaround,

*For Example* : From Nexus 6 to Pixel emulator

--happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

After declaring correctly in pubspec.yaml, consider giving full path of the image ex.

```
'assets/images/about_us.png'
```

instead of just `images/..`

worked for me after wasting 2 hours on such a trivial error.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue . The issue on my side was that the image name was having the space in between its name so I updated the image name with the new name that does not have any space.

Image name creating the error was  comboclr emtpy no circle.png

I updated this name to  comboclr_emtpy_no_circle.png

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and very nearly gave up on Flutter until I stumbled upon the cause.  In my case what I was doing was along the following lines

```
static Future<String> resourceText(String resName) async
{
 try
 { 
  ZLibCodec zlc = new ZLibCodec(gzip:false,raw:true,level:9);
  var data= await rootBundle.load('assets/path/to/$resName');
  String result = new 
  String.fromCharCodes(zlc.decode(puzzleData.buffer.asUint8List()));
  return puzzle;
 } catch(e)
 {
  debugPrint('Resource Error $resName $e');
  return ''; 
 } 
}

static Future<String> fallBackText(String textName) async
{
 if (testCondtion) return 'Some Required Text';
 else return resourceText('default');
}
```

where *Some Required Text* was a text string sent back if the `testCondition` was being met.  Failing that I was trying to pick up default text from the app resources and send that back instead.  My mistake was in the line `return resourceText('default');`.  After changing it to read `return await resourceText('default')` things worked just as expected.

This issue arises from the fact that `rootBundle.load` operates asynchronously.  In order to return its results correctly we need to `await` their availability which I had failed to do.  It strikes me as slightly surprising that neither the Flutter VSCode plugin nor the Flutter build process flag up this as an error.  While there may well be other reasons why `rootBundle.load` fails this answer will, hopefully, help others who are running into mysterious asset load failures in Flutter.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was nested folders.

I had my image in `assets/images/logo/xyz.png` and thought that `- assets/images/` would catch all subfolders.

You have to explicitly add each nested subfolder

Solution:
`- assets/images/logo/` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I put my images in a subdirectory of the assets folder.
Whenever I add new images, I restart the application and it works fine.

```
 assets:
    - assets/sub_folder/
```

I do this so that I don't have to list each asset name.

Answer (score 1):

**Well in case you have changed everything in the indentation part as told and checked for the typo errors but still get an error then you should do this simple which worked for me and it seems this is overlooked by almost everyone**

even if you have correct spacing after the assets: you still might be doinbg this one thing wrong

keep the indentation in this order

flutter:
<2_spaces>assets:
<no_space>- assets/images/image.png

thus it should look like this

```
flutter:
  assets:
  - assets/images/image.png
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when trying to add an image to a module inside a larger project turns out the Image.asset widget takes a packages parameter that you can specify, after specifying it worked just fine

Answer (score 1):

I have facing this problem. I do `flutter clean`, I do `Hot Restart`, check the `pubspec.yaml`. But everything seems fine.

My problem is at the file name, please check your lower case and upper case of your filename.

My problem is like this.

file name

```
images/Pizza0.png
```

error

```
AssetImage pizzaAsset = AssetImage('images/pizza0.png');
```

work

```
 AssetImage pizzaAsset = AssetImage('images/Pizza0.png');
```

Answer (score 1):

first Check assets path in pubspec.yaml
and also run
flutter clean Command

Answer (score 1):

The one thing that was missing from all of these (many duplicates) answers (for android) was this - The pubspec.yaml file needed (for me at least) to reference the asset file using direct reference (note the './' below):

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - ./assets/images/
```

Note that this assumes your assets/images folders are in the root of the project (the same folder that pubspec.yaml is in).  This will allow any image in the images folder to be accessible:

```
child: Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/Players.png"))
```

Answer (score 1):

In pubspec.yaml check the indent in assets and in assets set lines.
In assets line it should be 1 tab or 2 space, and in assets set line, it should be 2 tab or 4 spaces.

```
  assets:
    - assets/1.jpeg
```

**[1 Tab or 2 space]  assets:**

**[2 Tab or 4 space]    - assets/1.jpeg**

[image]

After all is done restart the app.
Remember Don't use hot reload or hot restart. It won't work.

Answer (score 1):

**if you think everything is ok in pubsepec.yaml . and you wrote the path of the image well then do the following :**

1-Fixed By Running :
=>`flutter clean` then => `flutter pub get`

2-close your app and remove it from background apps and
=>  `run it again`

it should appears now ✅

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs in when images are not properly updated in pubspec.yaml

Follow the steps to add a image to flutter:

1)create assets folder in project(inplace of assets you can create as your wish like images or else).
[image: creating assets directory in project]

2)add images into assets folder(or drag and drop image to assets).
[image: adding images into assets folder]

3)open pubspec.yaml file
[image: create a assets dependency and add a images which are already available in assets folder and run command from terminal pubget or press ctrl+s to save it will run and update,or press the download arrow which appears in top to update, once updated successfully in output console you can see exitcode 0.].

follow the above picture: create a assets dependency and add a images which are already available in assets folder and run command from terminal pubget or press ctrl+s to save it will run and update images ,or press the download arrow which appears in top to update images, once updated successfully in output console you can see exitcode 0.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
Image.asset( 'assets\\images\\logo.png')
```

worked for me,
need to specify the relative image path in puspec.yaml file

Comment: Backslash not working.

Answer (score 0):

For **Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1**:
If you have your asset path in **pubspec.yaml** file set to 'images/' or whatever naming you have preferred then

> flutter clean

OR you can go to `Tools` -> `Flutter` -> `Flutter clean`

& then hot-restart should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem and I found no problem in pubspec.yaml. However, restarting vscode worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
Image.asset('images/heart.png', fit: BoxFit.cover,width: 450, ),
```

Setting the width worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe happens because Windows OS uses \ as a directory separator.
you can do this:

You can create a “raw” string by prefixing it with r:

```
AssetImage(r'images\icon.png')
```

or

use the forward slash /

```
AssetImage('images/icon.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a project with many modules could be the case of your module is not accessing the right assets folders.
To fix this you have to specify your package name:

**Using Flutter SVG**

```dart
SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/image1.svg", package: "<my_package_name>", width: 100, height: 100,),
```

**Using Image.asset**

```dart
Image.asset(AssetImage("assets/images/image1.png").assetName, package: "<my_package_name>",);
```

and don't forget of specifying your assets in `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
```

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56366483/8266386) for further details

Answer (score 0):

If everything is as it should be and problem still exist.

Here is my suggestion :

Write specified path in "pubspec.yaml".

```
  assets:
- assets/images/x.png
```

After pub get, yellow line will appear to tell you file doesn't exist.

Then Refactoring your file name will make disappear that yellow line and ide will recognize your existing file.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

#### For windows

In my case I has to change `Image.asset` to `Image.file`:

from:

```dart
Image.asset(r"C:\path\to\file");
```

to:

```dart
Image.file(File(r"C:\path\to\file");
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had to run `pod install` in the iOS dir again

Answer (score -3):

Please provide the exact image name(including the extension) as specified in the images folder. A mismatch can trigger this exception.