# Flutter Package Reading its Own Assets

Tags: flutter, dart, assets

I have an module with an 'assets' folder located in the same directory as my pubspec.yaml file.  In my assets folder I have test.txt, and simpleObject.json.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/test.txt
    - assets/simpleObject.json
```

I believe the following code should then allow me to read it into my app.

```
var test = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/test.txt");
```

Sadly I get the following error:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/test.txt

The error comes from the asset_bundle.dart.  I have to assume this is my fault, but according to everything I've read I'm doing it correctly.  Any thoughts?

Here is my file structure if it helps.

```
MyModule
    |_assets/test.txt
    |_lib/
    |_pubspec.yaml
```

Comment: Did you try it with `rootBundle` and make sure you stop the app process and make a fresh app run.

Comment: Yes, it is the same result.

Comment: And what about your `simpleObject.json` does it get loaded successfully?

Comment: No, it does not load either.  Same error.

Comment: OK, can you show the directory tree where you have added these files?

Comment: I updated my original post.  Does that help?

Comment: did you try `flutter packages get`?

Comment: Everything seems to be fine if you have also run `flutter packages get`.

Comment: yeah, I ran flutter packages get on both the module and the app hosting it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I got a solution.  Even though my package was trying to load its own asset, it still had to specify itself as the location.

Here is how my_package loads an image asset (specifying the package), uses it in a widget, and that widget is easily used by outside apps.

```
Image.asset(AssetImage("assets/splash.png").assetName, package: 'my_package',);
```

Comment: Another solution can be: Image.asset('packages/<package_name>/assets/splash.png');

Comment: @DominicOrga you just saved my day!
Please add your solution as an answer so that others can see... Comments are not often read

Comment: did you also find a solution for loading assets which are not images?

Answer (score 14):

This is a bit late, but another solution can be:

```
Image.asset('packages/<package_name>/assets/splash.png');
```

Comment: This is a great way if there is no package argument, like a `RiveAnimation.asset(...)` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem and took a lot of time before it was resolved.
The solution was to downgrade to a previous version (git checkout v1.5.4-hotfix.2)