# showing error as Expected "assets" to be a list, but got -assets/tulas1.jpg (String). in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-image

[screenshot of a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M543C.png)while debugging it is showing error as you can see in screenshot

error=>"Expected "assets" to be a list, but got -assets/tulas1.jpg (String)."

I am new in programming and flutter. I got stuck while adding image to the pubsec.yaml.
please help me this error is giving me headache

Comment: @diegoveloper https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659809/fluttererror-unable-to-load-asset  this problem is different from mine.

Comment: don't forget the spaces:   -assets/tulas1.jpg  =>  -  assets/tulas1.jpg

Comment: sir i have done that too still same error. It is saying =>       Expected "assets" to be a list, but got -assets/tulas1.jpg (String).             what does this mean??

Comment: add `enter` after assets:

Comment: just add the space between - and assets/tulas1.jpg.