# Unable to load asset error while loading image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have given two white spaces for assets and 4 white spaces for the image location but also I am getting the error.

This is my `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/port.jpeg
```

**I am getting the error**

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/port.jpeg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 236:49  throw_
packages/flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart 227:55                        load
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1362:47                                          _rootRunUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1265:19                                          runUnary
...
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/port.jpeg")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#5a8a3(), name: "assets/port.jpeg", scale: 1)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

This is my directory

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code where you are using the image? Usually, in pubspec.yaml, under assets, you declare only a folder named "images" (you named it "assets" again) and then in the code you enter the image you want from that folder.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659809/fluttererror-unable-to-load-asset

Answer (score 0):

Just make a hot restart. If that doesn't fix your problem, uninstall and re-run your app in your emulator and you'll be fine

Answer (score -1):

write your asset as:-

```
 assets:
   - assets/
```

Answer (score -1):

```
assets:
    
    - assets/port.jpeg
```

Also, make sure the extension of the image matches the destination image extension.

Comment: thank your  for your response it worked after flutter clean and restart