# I keep receiving an error that says Flutter Error Unable to Load Asset

Tags: flutter, flutter-assetimage

I'm new to flutter. While adding an image and trying to run I got an error that said "Flutter Error Unable to load asset". An image of the problem can be seen below. If anyone can help that would be really appreciated! IMAGE: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZzvM.png]

Comment: Did you defined the asset in your pubspec.yaml? Remember to pay attention to identention when configuring pubspec.yaml.

Comment: Hi, yes I believe I have defined the asset, and I made sure my indentation was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your pubspec.yaml file for proper indentation. Also, once declared in pubspec, you're supposed to get dependencies in source code. Have you done both?
Also, check this thread - [fluttererror-unableToLoadAsset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659809/fluttererror-unable-to-load-asset)

Comment: Yes, I have. I checked my indentation many times as well.

Comment: Please check if this thread helps you 
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659809/fluttererror-unable-to-load-asset

Answer (score 0):

Please check your folder name.

You have written `asssets` instead of `assets` that is why the error is occuring.

Comment: I have fixed that but yet the error still occurs.

Comment: Can you please show the code part where you have called the asset. I think the way you called is incorrect. Also please show the pubspec.yaml file also (The asset part)

Comment: Hello, attached are images- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KCzeDoN3lfwe06iuDIFic_s3k6EMh3fF/view?usp=sharing and https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PCGWuQOw42Up62QtaGp3wS1BVHVzUCdd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I did not find any problems, but are you getting any errors when running pub get. Coz there's a error code 1 in your terminal. This could be the reason that the assets are not registered. Do pub get and see where is the error coming from.