# Assets is being loaded in cache but not found for AudioPlayer

Tags: flutter

I'm using the package: audioplayers: ^1.0.1

I'm trying to follow the migration guide of audioplayers found in this link: https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/migration_guide.md

But I can't make it to work.

Here's my pubspec

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/sounds/
```

If I do it like this, it can't load the *assets*.

```
  final playerSound = AudioPlayer();
  await playerSound.setSource(AssetSource('assets/sounds/Pop (1).wav'));

Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/assets/sounds/Pop (1).wav
```

But if I remove the *assets*, it is trying to find in the cache. I don't get why it is working. Please help to clarify. Thanks!

```
final playerSound = AudioPlayer();
  await playerSound.setSource(AssetSource('sounds/Pop (1).wav'));

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.MyName.MyApp/cache/sounds/Pop%20(1).wav: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

[image: This is the assets folder with the Pop (1).wav on it]

Comment: Can you show the aseets folder in picture format.

Comment: I have added the picture

Comment: @Mr.Tacio Changing the name of your file might help. Try like this - test.wav

Comment: Take a look here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53659937/10498374

Comment: Great! Thanks Olek L. and farouk osama. Changing the name worked. It doesn't have an issue before upgrade but now, it has that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the spaces in the name. It is now working. Thanks to @Olek L. and @farouk osama

Answer (score 3):

Ok so what i see from the package structure.

If you Go into the AssetSource class which looks as follows :

source.dart file

```
/// Source representing the path of an application asset in your Flutter
/// "assets" folder.
/// Note that a prefix might be applied by your [AudioPlayer]'s audio cache
/// instance.
class AssetSource extends Source {
  final String path;
  AssetSource(this.path);

  @override
  Future<void> setOnPlayer(AudioPlayer player) {
    return player.setSourceAsset(path);
  }
}
```

Here if you go inside the  setSourceAsset method :

```
 /// Sets the URL to an asset in your Flutter application.
  /// The global instance of AudioCache will be used by default.
  ///
  /// The resources will start being fetched or buffered as soon as you call
  /// this method.
  Future<void> setSourceAsset(String path) async {
    final url = await audioCache.load(path);
    return _platform.setSourceUrl(playerId, url.path, isLocal: true);
  }
```

if you see the line

```
 final url = await audioCache.load(path);
```

so this in this AudioCache class if you see the constructor :

```
  /// This is the path inside your assets folder where your files lie.
  ///
  /// For example, Flame uses the prefix 'assets/audio/'
  /// (you must include the final slash!).
  /// The default prefix (if not provided) is 'assets/'
  /// Your files will be found at <prefix><fileName> (so the trailing slash is
  /// crucial).
  String prefix;

  AudioCache({this.prefix = 'assets/'});
```

So the prefix is assets added as a default in the constructor. So you don't have to call it every time only the file name followed by the folder if you are adding in any case.

Comment: But when I did this, await playerSound.setSource(AssetSource('sounds/Pop (1).wav')); it was having a not found error. And it is looking in cache. I still don't understand.

Comment: Hey @Mr.Tacio have you got the solution for the above you mentioned.

Comment: Removing the spaces solved my issue.